# Hide specific file from Git public Repo

Tags: git, github, heroku

I am making an Economy Discord bot and I want to make the code open source. Currently, I have a private repo for the code. The bot is being hosted on Heroku and is set to whenever the "Master" branch updates, it will auto-deploy the app.[image: Heroku settings set to autodeploy from master branch] But I have 2 details that I dont want the open source repo to have. The bots token and a server url that is used to store users data. I dont want the open source repo to have the server url and the token.

Both the token and server url are stored in a .JSON file which will be accessed from the main index.js file. Here is how it looks like:

```json
{
token: "Token_here",
server: "Server_URL_Here"
}
```

Is there a way to make it so that Heroku and I will have access to the JSON file but the people who is viewing the open source repo to not see the JSON file? Is this possible?

Comment: Remove secrets from the code, and inject them on the CICD, never put secret into git

Comment: Sounds like you will have to rewrite history so that you have a _public_ branch without that and a downstream _private_ branch where you will have all those details.

Comment: ... but @Ôrel's advice is pretty sound,

Comment: @Ôrel How do I inject on CICD? Sorry I'm a bit new to Git.

Comment: @eftshift0ah but if i commit on the private branch with the secret stuff, will it auto-commit on public without secret stuff? or do i have to manually recommit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives, including "[git-crypt](https://www.agwa.name/git/git-crypt.git/raw/master/README)"

- https://buddy.works/guides/git-crypt):
- https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/keeping-sensitive-data-secret-git-repository/

Since you're using Heroku, this might be your best bet:

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/182074/76526
>
> The preferred method of keeping passwords/api keys secret on heroku is
> to set config values via the heroku commandline application. The
> following example taken from [a heroku dev center
> article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)
>
> (The below example, and my entire answer relate to rails apps)
>
> ```
> $ cd myapp
> $ heroku config:add S3_KEY=8N029N81 S3_SECRET=9s83109d3+583493190
> Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v14
> S3_KEY:     8N029N81
> S3_SECRET:  9s83109d3+583493190
> ```
>
> Then reference these config values in your code using the ENV[]
> variable
>
> ```
> AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
>   :access_key_id     => ENV['S3_KEY'],
>   :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
> )
> ```
>
> This way your sensitive passwords are not stored in the git
> repository.  (Note: When running the app locally, set these values in
> your `.bashrc` file
>
> Also, I'm not sure what type of application you are running, but in
> Rails, heroku does not use your database.yml file, it simply sets your
> database username/password according to your app settings. So you can
> avoid saving those credentials in git
>
> Also, also, if you are running your own application and want it to
> remain private, a great alternative to github is
> [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) which offer free private
> repositories.

---

ADDENDUM:

> It is working now I had to use .env instead of .bashrc and instead of
> ENV I had to use process.env.TOKEN, also I had to use the dotenv
> module at the start of the file([npmjs.com/package/dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)) – Coder
> Gautam YT

Comment: Ok I created .bashrc file for local testing

Comment: It looks like
`TOKEN="tokenhere"`

Comment: But when i refer it in code `client.login(ENV[token])` i get ENV is not defined

Comment: It is working now I had to use .env instead of .bashrc and instead of ENV I had to use process.env.TOKEN, also I had to use the dotenv module at the start of the file(https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)